# Count how many times a method is executed

Tags: objective-c, methods, count, execution

Is there any chance to count how many times one of my methods is executed and on the base of that to do something?

Thanks

Comment: No, i just want to understand is it possible and how? I have a button that must be clicked. If it isn't an alert shows. I want to count how many times this alert shows to disable the button when the count is 50 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare one static variable and increment the same inside your method. After that you can see the count.

Below is the sample code:-

```
static int i=0; //declare outside your method

-(void)yourMethod{
    ++i;
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain Shabbir, I will check it and let you know.

Comment: I don't want to help feed a potential help vampire but your answer is missing an important part to completely answer the OPs question: The conditional the evaluates the static variable and performs some action. The OP's comment to the question makes it more concrete.

Comment: Thanks Paul, So it should be non static variable??

Comment: FYI - declare the static variable inside the method since the variable is only needed (I believe) inside the method.

Comment: Ok so according to you should be global variable not static??